# Elegantly merging rows on Spark, based on multiple conditions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Heyo StackOverflow,

Currently trying to find an elegant way to do a specific transformation.

So I have a dataframe of actions, that looks like this:

```
+---------+----------+----------+---------+
|timestamp|   user_id|    action|    value|
+---------+----------+----------+---------+
|      100|         1|     click|     null|
|      101|         2|     click|     null|
|      103|         1|      drag|      AAA|
|      101|         1|     click|     null|
|      108|         1|     click|     null|
|      100|         2|     click|     null|
|      106|         1|      drag|      BBB|
+---------+----------+----------+---------+
```

Context:
Users can perform actions: clicks and drags. Clicks don't have a value, drags do. A drag implies there was a click but not the other way around. Let's also assume that the drag event can be recorded *after* or *before* the click event.
So I have, for each drag, a **corresponding** click action. What I would like to do, is merge the drag and click actions into 1, ie. delete the drag action after giving its `value` to the click action.

To know which click corresponds to which drag, I have to take the click whose timestamp is the closest to the drag's `timestamp`. I also want to make sure that a drag cannot be linked to a click if there timestamp difference is over 5 (and that means some drags might not be linked, it's fine). Of course, I don't want the drag of user 1 to correspond to the click of user 2.

Here, the result would look like this:

```
+---------+----------+----------+---------+
|timestamp|   user_id|    action|    value|
+---------+----------+----------+---------+
|      100|         1|     click|     null|
|      101|         2|     click|     null|
|      101|         1|     click|      AAA|
|      108|         1|     click|      BBB|
|      100|         2|     click|     null|
+---------+----------+----------+---------+
```

The drag with `AAA` (`timestamp` = 103) was linked to the click that happened at 101 because it's the closest to 103. Same logic for `BBB`.

So I would like to perform these operations, in a smooth/efficient way. So far, I have something like this:

```
val window =  Window partitionBy ($"user_id") orderBy $"timestamp".asc

myDF
  .withColumn("previous_value", lag("value", 1, null) over window)
  .withColumn("previous_timestamp", lag("timestamp", 1, null) over window)
  .withColumn("next_value", lead("value", 1, null) over window)
  .withColumn("next_timestamp", lead("timestamp", 1, null) over window)

  .withColumn("value",
        when(
            $"previous_value".isNotNull and
            // If there is more than 5 sec. difference, it shouldn't be joined
            $"timestamp" - $"previous_timestamp" < 5 and
            (
                $"next_timestamp".isNull or
                $"next_timestamp" - $"timestamp" > $"timestamp" - $"previous_timestamp"
            ), $"previous_value")
        .otherwise(
            when($"next_timestamp" - $"timestamp" < 5, $"next_value")
            .otherwise(null)
        )
    )
  .filter($"action" === "click")
  .drop("previous_value")
  .drop("previous_timestamp")
  .drop("next_value")
  .drop("next_timestamp")
```

But I feel this is rather inefficient. Is there a better way to do this ? (something that can be done without having to create 4 temporary columns...)
Is there a way to manipulate both the row with offset -1 and +1 in the same expression for example ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt using Spark-SQL rather than DataFrame APIs, but it should be possible to convert:

```scala
myDF.registerTempTable("mydf")

spark.sql("""
with
 clicks_table as (select * from mydf where action='click')
,drags_table  as (select * from mydf where action='drag' )

,one_click_many_drags as (
  select
    c.timestamp as c_timestamp
    , d.timestamp as d_timestamp
    , c.user_id as c_user_id
    , d.user_id as d_user_id
    , c.action as c_action
    , d.action as d_action
    , c.value as c_value
    , d.value as d_value
  from clicks_table c
  inner join drags_table d
  on c.user_id = d.user_id
    and abs(c.timestamp - d.timestamp) <= 5 --a drag cannot be linked to a click if there timestamp difference is over 5
)
,one_click_one_drag as (
  select c_timestamp as timestamp, c_user_id as user_id, c_action as action, d_value as value
  from (
    select *, row_number() over (
      partition by d_user_id, d_timestamp --for each drag timestamp with multiple possible click timestamps, we rank the click timestamps by nearness
      order by
        abs(c_timestamp - d_timestamp) asc --prefer nearest
        , c_timestamp asc --prefer next_value if tied
    ) as rn
    from one_click_many_drags
  ) 
  where rn=1 --take only the best match for each drag timestamp
)

--now we start from the clicks_table and add in the desired drag values!

select c.timestamp, c.user_id, c.action, m.value
from clicks_table c
left join one_click_one_drag m
on c.user_id = m.user_id
and c.timestamp = m.timestamp

""")
```

Tested to produce your desired output.

Comment: I had considered the "join" way but could not manage to get quite the right thing, the use of the rank is really what I had missed out! This is already much cleaner, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! Take note that this method doesn't work well if `timestamp`+ `user_id` is not unique!

Comment: True, but I simplified my problem: each event actually has an ID, which works as a primary key ;) But thanks for looking out, and for taking the time to find this nice solution!